# Android Camera2 API JPEG_QUALITY not available

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to work on my Nexus 5x with android `Camera2 APIs` and I am using [googlesamples android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

My problem is that the JPEG images have too low quality and their size is much smaller that regular images I am taking with my phone camera app.

According to google documents there should be a key `JPEG_QUALITY` both in CaptureRequest and in CaptureResult:

> JPEG_QUALITY
>
> Added in API level 21
>
> Key JPEG_QUALITY
>
> Compression quality of the final JPEG image.
>
> 85-95 is typical usage range.
>
> Range of valid values:
>
> 1-100; larger is higher quality
>
> This key is available on all devices.

However when I ask for the available keys, `JPEG_QUALITY` key is not available so I don't how to know what is my current `JPEG` compression quallity used and how I can change it.

The code I did inside:

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {

               
                //_TEST_DEBUG
                List<CaptureRequest.Key<?>> requestKeys = request.getKeys();
                List<CaptureResult.Key<?>> resultKeys = result.getKeys();
```

requestKeys & resultKeys have many keys including `JPEG_ORIENTATION` but not the `JPEG_QUALITY` key.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Why can't I find how to change `JPEG` compression quality?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 9):

I achieved increasing the JPEG quality by adding it as a key to the CaptureRequest.Builder in the googlesamples android-Camera2Basic with a Tesco Hudl 2 Tablet on Android 5.1 Lollipop.

The JPEG quality is set in the captureStillPicture() method in the Camer2BasicFragment like so:

```
        // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

        //Set the JPEG quality here like so
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)90);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is exectly that i looking for, but maybe you know why if i set quality `100` i get my saved image is quality 96?

Comment: No - could you tell me how you are discovering the compression quality so I can try and replicate your results with my device.

Comment: I discovered it with help of `JPEGsnoop` ... If you could, try it with your device. Thanks!

Comment: @BlinkingCahill: The image quality is still low when I add the code `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)90);`. I used other apps and it got a good quality

Comment: @user3051460 What was the solution you ended up using? Was it something which can be utilized within a camera2 implementation?